# Octave: Can't Display Image?

Tags: image, matlab, octave

I'm having basic difficulty getting an image to show with Octave.

In particular, the following code:

```
img1 = imread('data1/image2.jpg');
imshow (img1)
```

Shows no image. However, if `drawnow()` is added at the end, the image will pop up momentarily and then disappear. If `ginput()` is added instead, the image will politely stay showing until input is done. How can I simply get the image to show?

Thanks!

Comment: What os, what octave version, etc? Need more information. Getting any errors, warnings, etc? Only this one image or all images can be shown?

Comment: octave version 3.6.2 on debian wheezy. No errors reported except `warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel` which appears whether or not the image is in fact shown (i.e. whether `image` or `ginput` is called.

Comment: `imshow` uses `image` function. Does `image` function also don't work? I have 3.6.4 on ubuntu 13.10 x64 and everthing is ok. Maybe some bug.

Comment: Yes, `image` doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using the not recommended QtOctave and if so, does the problem goes away if don't use it?

Comment: I'm using octave from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the code as a script file from the linux terminal? Eg: `$ octave HelloWorld.m`

If so, what I believe happened is that the script file reached the end, closing the image window before it could display anything (or pop up for that matter).

Adding `drawnow()` redraws the image if any image property is changed.

In this case, no image property is changed so `drawnow()` doesn't do anything. But `drawnow()` can still be useful in that it waits for the image to pop out before letting the program move on to the next line. (Hence the momentarily appearance) Still, the script will end and the window will close...

A simple workaround would be to add a `pause()`, `input()` or `ginput()` at the end of the script. Just don't let the script end. Or you could type your code in the octave command line itself.